# a curve running **through** space

Tags: meaning

A speaker describes this graph

[image]

as

> this is a curve running **through** space.

I understand "through" means

> from one end or side of something to the other

source [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/through).

So, does "through" space means the following? I really don't understand what does "one end of space" mean.

> from one end of space to the other end of space

Answer (score 1):

Here is another sense of "through":
[Merriam-Webster "through" 3b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through)
preposition 
3b —used as a function word to indicate movement within a large expanse
*flew through the air*

In any case, the speaker may not have expressed the idea very well. They might as well have said "This is a curve in a plane."

I agree that space doesn't have beginning or end.

Comment: Given the shape of the curve, I suspect this was in the context of a point on the edge of a wheel as it rolls across a surface, in which case I think the speaker may have been attempting to express that the drawing *represents* a curve through physical space as a wheel rolls through that space, so in that case, "space" is appropriate, and "plane" would not be.  Without context it's hard to say, though..

Comment: I think, as long as the wheel isn't turning, that plane would still fit.